# What is the difference between touch file and > file?

Tags: command-line

I am kind of newbie to Linux, and I wonder whether or not `>` and `touch` have the same effect. I mean, do the following two commands have the same effect?:

```
$ > file.txt

$ touch file.txt
```

If so, it would be great to know that I can just type `> file.txt' to create new files.

Comment: If `file.txt` already exists and is not empty, they certainly don't.

Comment: @fkraiem, could you please make an elaborated answer?

Comment: He's saying if you `touch` a file that contains data nothing will happen but if you `>` the file it will be erased.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for that clarification @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: Would you like to answer the question, have me answer the question, have @fkraiem answer it, or delete it?

Comment: See this is what happens when people answer in comments. Nobody knows what to do now.

Comment: One of them is clear and readable and one is not.

Comment: Related: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Both `touch` and `>` will create a new file if it doesn't exist. As the following terminal commands show when you `touch` an existing file the access/last modified time are updated. But if you `>` to an existing file it is truncated and the last modified time is updated (access time is not).  Note that `>` does not delete/unlink the file.  The inode stays the same -- which is why `>` / or `truncate` are commonly used to clear out log files even with an open file handle.

```
rick@dell:~$ > EmptyFile

rick@dell:~$ touch EmptyFile2

rick@dell:~$ ls Empty*
EmptyFile  EmptyFile2

rick@dell:~$ ls -l Empty*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 0 Sep 29 20:27 EmptyFile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 0 Sep 29 20:27 EmptyFile2

rick@dell:~$ echo Hello > EmptyFile

rick@dell:~$ ls -l Empty*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 6 Sep 29 20:28 EmptyFile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 0 Sep 29 20:27 EmptyFile2

rick@dell:~$ > EmptyFile

rick@dell:~$ ls -l Empty*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 0 Sep 29 20:28 EmptyFile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 0 Sep 29 20:27 EmptyFile2

rick@dell:~$ echo Hello > EmptyFile

rick@dell:~$ touch EmptyFile

rick@dell:~$ ls -l Empty*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 6 Sep 29 20:32 EmptyFile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 0 Sep 29 20:27 EmptyFile2
```

---

As mentioned in comments, `touch` is an external command and only operates on files. `>` is a shell built-in feature that serves many different purposes. Sometimes you would see it used like `cat Source.txt > Target.txt`.

A long form to empty a file would be:

```
cat /dev/null > EmptyMe.txt
```

Using `> EmptyMe.txt` accomplishes the same thing in a compact format of redirecting nothing to the file.

Comment: Use case: `> file.txt` is good for clearing out log files.

Comment: It's not actually re-created.  The existing file is truncated, which is different from unlinking the old file and creating a new one.  The biggest observable difference is that if a process still has the old file open or mapped, it would still exist.  But truncating would affect the file that other processes have open.

Comment: Not sure about "biggest observable" -- it's easy to observe whether hardlinks are broken (if you `ln foo bar`, and then delete and recreate `foo`, `bar` still has its prior contents).

Comment: Oh yes, that's an even more easily observable difference.  I should have thought of that :P

Comment: @Charles-Duffy Sure, when there are 2 links to a fie that would be obvious I guess, that has nothing to do with what Peter Cordes was saying though.  When you delete/unlink a file that is currently in use/has open filehandle it isn't deleted. for example, say you `rm /var/log/nginx/access.log` while nginx had that file open it would have 0 links but the inode would still exist.  `lsof -c nginx | grep access.log` then with the pid, `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd/ | grep access.log` and finally cat /proc/<pid>/fd/<filename from previous command>`.  Commenting even though this is old. Hope it made sense

Comment: You may also wanna mention `>` is a shell operator and can be used to manipulate file descriptors. `touch` is an external command, and expects files.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy It might open a can of worms getting into all the ways `>` can be used. eg With `awk` today I posted `$1>$2` for picture width greater than picture height. Also we can get into `&1>&2` for file redirection. Then `cat /dev/null > emptyme.fil` which I did add into the answer. Please feel free to edit answer to your heart's content. Everyone knows you're a star in this field :)

Answer (score 14):

There's a substantial difference between the two.  `Touch` is a command used to time stamp a file.  The `>` symbol is a standard output redirector.

### **Usage of the two explained**

**Usage of Touch**

If the file doesn't exist it will create the file.

**Touch** is commonly used to create flags.  For instance if you want to find all files between two times on your system you could use this sequence of commands:

```
$ touch -t 201609292200 starttime 
$ touch -t 201609292300 endtime
```

This will create the following files (or change the time-stamp if they exist):

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ljames ljames 0 Sep 29 23:00 endtime
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ljames ljames 0 Sep 29 22:00 starttime
```

Now you can use find to display or process all files that were modified on that hour (time between those two files time stamps, i.e. between 10 PM and 11 PM of September 29, 2016).

```bash
$ find ~/ -newer starttime ! -newer endtime -printf "%M %Tm/%Td %TH:%TM %TM %p\n"
```

This is a partial output of the above find command:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 09/29 22:08 08 /home/users/l/j/ljames/.thunderbird/lj7p62iq.default/gcontactsync/google_feed_backups/apollothethird@gmail.com_groups.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 09/29 22:08 08 /home/users/l/j/ljames/.thunderbird/lj7p62iq.default/gcontactsync/google_feed_backups/apollothethird@gmail.com.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 09/29 22:08 08 /home/users/l/j/ljames/.thunderbird/lj7p62iq.default/gcontactsync/address_book_backups/abook.mab.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 09/29 23:00 00 /home/users/l/j/ljames/endtime
drwx------ 09/29 22:44 44 /home/users/l/j/ljames/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/Temp
drwx------ 09/29 22:44 44 /home/users/l/j/ljames/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/fahmaaghhglfmonjliepjlchgpgfmobi
drwx------ 09/29 22:44 44 /home/users/l/j/ljames/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/fahmaaghhglfmonjliepjlchgpgfmobi/1.337.0_0
```

**Usage of Output redirection**

**The redirecting Symbol** will redirect standard output to the specified file.  Depending on your clobber/noclobber settings if could fail.  Noclobber will only create the file if it doesn't exist.

There are a number of versions of the redirection output which includes:

```
>   - Redirect standard output. Create or overwrite the existing file.
>>  - Redirect append.  Create or append to existing file.
>&  - Redirect both standard output and standard error.
>>& - Redirect/Append both standard output and standard error
```

We could use our `find` command above to redirect the contents of all files created within the specified hour to a file that we could log and study later:

```bash
$ find ~/ -newer starttime ! -newer endtime -printf "%M %Tm/%Td %TH:%TM %TM %p\n" > ~/files.log
```

Comment: Many people have mentioned that, if `file.txt` exists and is not empty, then `> file.txt` will clear out its contents but `touch file.txt` will not.   But nobody has mentioned that `>> file.txt` is a good substitute for `touch file.txt` — it will create the file if it doesn't exist (assuming that you have permission to do so), but it will not truncate an existing file.   See [What is the difference between “>” and “>>”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/558043/325633)

Comment: This is explained in the section `Usage of Output redirection`.  Notice is says `>>` = `Redirect append>`.

Comment: Yes, and that's perfectly clear — to people who already know it. Put yourself in the shoes of the OP — you've posted a wall of text that's **Too Long Too Read**; he's not going to understand from your answer that `>> file.txt` is a workable substitute for `touch file.txt`. (The fact that you're the only person who mentioned `>>` *at all* is why I posted my comment under your answer, rather than under the question.)

Comment: @G-Man Some people confuse the redirect symbol to be a substitute for touch.  However it's not a substitute.  The details of my answer is to clarify this mistake.  The examples of using the two is to help clarify it.  Please notice the first couple line answers the initial specifics of your current comment.  It says there is a significant difference between the two.  The OP is interested in the difference.  So the other parts of the answer is to respond to the OP's interest in the two.  There are different effects and there is a reasons for the difference.

Answer (score 9):

`>` is the shell output redirection operator, used to redirect STDOUT of the preceding command(s) to the file descriptor mentioned after `>`. If the file is present, it's content will be truncated, as file with be `open(2)`-ed with `O_TRUNC` flag, and if the file doesn't exist, it will be created.

Important thing to note that, this redirection operator will be handled by shell before the preceding command runs, so this doesn't depend on any command, and handled by shell itself.

Note that, some shells (e.g. `zsh`) will behave differently with empty redirection like:

```
 >file.txt
```

A typical workaround is to add the `:` (`true`) no-op command:

```
 : >file.txt
```

---

Traditionally, the main purpose of `touch` is to change the timestamp of a file, not creating a file.

`touch` creates a file, only when the file(s) mentioned in the argument doesn't exist, otherwise it changes the modification time of the file to current timestamp. You can also change access time, and inode creation time using `touch`.

Comment: `zsh` does support empty redirection - it acts quite similarly to redirecting `cat` with no arguments to a file. Basically whatever you type will be written to the file until an EOF character or an interrupt. This mirrors `zsh`'s behavior with just `<file`, which simply prints the file contents, as `cat` would do. These may be configurable, I have seen `<file` open the file in a pager.

Comment: @8bittree What i meant is you need to input `EOF` (like doing `cat >file.txt` as you have said), where in `bash` just doing `>file.txt` would suffice.

Comment: Fair enough, I suggested an edit that I think gets the idea across more clearly.

Comment: @8bittree Approved.

Comment: (1) By default, `touch` updates both the modification time and the access time of the file.   There are options to update only one or the other.   (2) Unix / Linux / POSIX do not support “inode creation time”, in general.   Some file system types support it, but there is no universal way to look at it, let alone modify it.   Can you provide a reference that says that there is an incarnation of `touch` that allows the user to change inode creation time?