# Only one line in script output

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

There are multiple lines in my input file (`SerialNos.csv`), like this:

```
4TF16B7GA129E
4TF16B7GA129S
4TF16B7GA129D
4TF16B7GA129X
```

I want to read each line, compute a checksum,
and write the result to another file,
but my output file `Token.csv` only has one output line. 
How can I process every line?

My Code:

```
epoch=$(date -d "`date`" +"%s")
StringCsv="/home/Desktop/TokenGenScript/SerialNos.csv"
StringToken=b5242a2d7973c1aca3723c834ba0d239

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
 j=$line
 serial=${j}:${epoch}:${StringToken}
 echo "$serial"|sha256sum > Token.csv
done < "$StringCsv"
```

Comment: and your code is not working or what is the problem? Btw, you don't need the doubled `date`.

Answer (score 6):

You are writing to a file in a loop with this command:

```
echo "$serial"|sha256sum > Token.csv
```

However each time you loop you are erasing the file and writing a new entry. What you want to do is append (add to) the file each time you loop with this command:

```
echo "$serial"|sha256sum >> Token.csv
```

A single `>` tells bash to erase the file `Token.csv` and write the contents. A double `>>` tells bash to add to the end of the file.

---

The bash script would now look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
epoch=$(date -d "`date`" +"%s")
StringCsv="/home/Desktop/TokenGenScript/SerialNos.csv"
StringToken=b5242a2d7973c1aca3723c834ba0d239

> Token.csv # Empty file from last run

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
 j=$line
 serial=${j}:${epoch}:${StringToken}
 echo "$serial"|sha256sum >> Token.csv # Append new record to end
done < "$StringCsv"
```

---

There are two ways to create a new empty file `> Token.csv` as used above and `touch Token.csv`. However only `> Token.csv` will empty an existing file. See:

- [What is the difference between touch file and > file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831414/what-is-the-difference-between-touch-file-and-file)

Comment: There should probably be an explicit removal/truncation of `Token.csv` prior to the loop, to assure this run doesn't append to any existing file contents.

Comment: As *you* explained in your answer to the question you linked to,  `touch` does ***not*** empty a file.

Comment: @Scott Yes that was misleading. I've reworded it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MontyHarder I've added a full script now.

Comment: @Scott Double thanks. OP never had a shebang in the first place which I was planning to mention in the answer as well. The whole second edit was rather rushed as I had a priority project under way.

Answer (score 6):

Put the output redirection on the entire loop, not just the `sha256sum` command. Every time you redirect, you're recreating the output file from scratch. This will just create it once, and write to it repeatedly within the loop.

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
 j=$line
 serial=${j}:${epoch}:${StringToken}
 echo "$serial"|sha256sum
done < "$StringCsv" > Token.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command below for reading n lines from file:

```
head -n 1 filename
```

to write it to variable use this:

```
var=$(head -n 1 filename);
```

Or you can read nth line from file:

```
sed -n '2p' filename
```

The comand above will return second line of file. For your example you can use this:
sed -n $i'p' filename
where i is index.

BUT, for your code you need an index that will increase every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Taking [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) **way** too seriously, and using GNU Awk's [getline from a Coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fCoprocess.html#Getline_002fCoprocess):

```
gawk -v stringToken=b5242a2d7973c1aca3723c834ba0d239 '
  BEGIN{cmd="sha256sum"; s = systime()} 
  {
    print $0 s stringToken |& cmd; close(cmd,"to"); 
    cmd |& getline; close(cmd,"from")
  } 1
' SerialNos.csv > Token.csv
```